# onCreateOptionsMenu called multiple times

Tags: java, android, menu

In my viewpager i have 5 fragments and each time i swipe between tabs, onCreateOptionsMenu in my MainActivity where i initialized my viewpager gets called multiple times.

I read in another post onCreateOptionsMenu is supposed to be called only once and onPrepareOptionsMenu is supposed to be called multiple times for updating purposes.

Second problem is that when i launch to another activity and then go back by pressing the back button and launch it again, onCreateOptionsMenu also gets called again which keeps inflating my menu in that activity.

Is this normal behavior or a bug because i have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Have your fragments in viewpager do setHasOptionsMenu(true)?It may cause their activity's onCreateOptionsMenu called when initializing.

Comment: @JiajiaGu No i didn't use setHasOptionsMenu in the fragments, only have onCreateOptionsMenu in my MainActivity.